# changing variables on click in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I am looking for is more of a toggle i suppose. basically I have this:

```
    <i class="checkbox pull-left" ng-click="changePrice()"></i>
```

I have a variable in my controller like so:

```
    $scope.basePrice = 10;
```

What i am looking to do, is on checking the box, switch the variable to a different number. Which I can do. My problem lies when i uncheck the box, and the variable doesnt switch back. I have tried an if/else if statement, ng-change, ng-click, i was thinking switch might work, but at this point, im clueless. Any help would be appreciated.

requested controller example:

```
app.controller('examplectrl', '[$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.basePrice = 10;
    $scope.changePrice = function(){
    if($('#changePrice.checked')){
     console.log("checked");
    }else{
     console.log("not checked.")
    }
    };
```

}]);

Comment: Can you show us your controller code ?

Comment: i will see what i can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a second variable that keep the toggle value as a `boolean`

The price is updated to 25 but you can add your own code there

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.basePrice = 10;

  $scope.priceToggle = false;

  $scope.changePrice = function() {
    $scope.priceToggle ? $scope.basePrice = 10: $scope.basePrice = 25;
    $scope.priceToggle = !$scope.priceToggle;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button class="checkbox pull-left" ng-click="changePrice()">Change price</button>
  <p ng-bind="basePrice"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using a controller function:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <i ng-init="basePrice = 10" class="checkbox pull-left" ng-click="basePrice = basePrice == 10 ? 25 : 10">PRICE</i>
  {{basePrice}}
</body>
```